# Canonical question for sorting with key argument in Python

Tags: discussion, canonical

In last 2 days I saw three questions <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34708898/3821804) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34721320/3821804) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34705205/3821804)</sup> asking about sorting Python list based on custom criterion.
In both cases, the answer is: *use `list.sort` or `sorted` with function as `key` argument*.
None of them is closed.

Questions like those [have been asked and answered at least several times before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+sorting?sort=votes).

Despite this, I can't find clear, high quality duplicate target!

Answers to all five highest voted questions tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)[sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorting) ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+sorting?sort=votes)) mention using `list.sort` or `sorted` with function as `key` argument, but, in every case the function is different.
Because of that, it feels wrong to flag as duplicate of one of those
(it's not *exact* duplicate, answers differ).

So, I started to looking for a case-agnostic explanation of `key`, and possibly it's predecessor, `cmp`.

**Do we have a canonical answer about `key` parameter in `list.sort` / `sorted`?**

If not, I'd suggest to write one.

The best (IMO) I could find is [What arguments does Python sort function have?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1972672/3821804).
Second best (IMO) is [Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda :)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8966538/3821804).

Summarizing:

If we have canonical, please point it to me.
If not, what should we do?
Do we edit one of those questions into canonicals?
Or one of those highly-upvoted ones, into case-agnostic?
Do you have a better question to turn into canonical?
Or maybe we should just write brand-new canonical from scratch?

<sup>This is my first request for canonical, so I'm open to every suggestion about improving my post.</sup>

Comment: Good luck writing canonical questions nowadays. Be sure to make the question matching for searches, and probably include the highest voted links to your question  and answer(s).

Comment: In general for [tag:python], see http://sopython.com/canon/

Answer (score 9):

Good question and yet another disappointingly low response. Let me take a stab at it; this is not the final answer, but a commentary illuminated by examples. Sadly the older and more answers/views/upvotes/citations a question has, the more obsolete its answers tend to be. Seems we need to retire old 2009 / pre-2.7/3.5 stuff.

Some questions which https://sopython.com/canon/ has made canonicals:

1. Category: [Sorting a list based on special / multiple criteria / keys](https://sopython.com/canon/89/sorting-a-list-based-on-special-multiple-criteria-keys/)

   1. [Sorting a Python list by two criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-criteria) -> close as duplicate of [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)
      . Do we let the first question stand and just restrict its scope to *"list-of-lists-of-length-two-builtin-types (e.g. string/int/float)"*. Or do we also allow *"list-of-user-defined-object"*, as the title suggests is also allowed, in which case the answer is *"Define **lt**() method on your class or inherit from some class that does"*?  That would make it a far better canonical.
   2. [Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda: ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda) is bad as a canonical because it should emphasize what you're trying to do (custom or arbitrary sort order on builtin or user-defined type) rather than insisting you must use lambda (which becomes less necessary every year), and that `operator.itemgetter` is usually the better way to go. (If it's a user-defined type, it should always define either `__lt__()` or `__cmp__()`: as per this one which should be canonical [Making a python user-defined class sortable, hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152497/making-a-python-user-defined-class-sortable-hashable)
   3. [What arguments does Python sort function have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972672/what-arguments-does-python-sort-function-have) is pretty pedestrian too, and dated 2.x stuff: really `sort(cmp=...)` is the last resort.
2. a niche case for custom sort-order [Sorting / comparing version strings eg ["1.1.2", "1.0.0"...]](https://sopython.com/canon/102/sorting-comparing-version-strings/)
3. and finally we have this old 2009 question which somewhat predated OrderedDict in 2.7 [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) and there's no proper explanation of "dict is ordered in CPython 3.6 implementation, although not in the language spec"

Some other questions which should be canonical:

- [What is the difference between `sorted(list)` vs `list.sort()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort-python)

Answer (score 4):

I did my best writing [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34865217/3821804) and answering it.

I think the question could've been written better, but, at the moment, I have no good idea how to improve it. If anyone has one, feel free to edit! I'll take another look at the question tomorrow.

---

Also, I've edited out unnecesary code from [What arguments does Python sort function have?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1972672/3821804)
and suggested to include it in http://sopython.com/canon (it's included now).

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question. There are many choices for canonical question on `sorted` syntax. Any question *specifically querying* how this syntax works should be closed as a duplicate of one of those. I won't get into a discussion on specific examples, as this is [covered well by @smci](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366510/9209546).

**Problem 1**

I believe that *many* of these questions, e.g. [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34721320/3821804) & [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34705205/3821804) in the examples you gave, are more concerned about how to formulate logic to fit the requirements of `sorted`. In my opinion, asking how to utilise a specific feature or method to fit a particular scenario should be in scope for SO.

We're getting to the stage that many specific usages are also duplicates. It is a problem. But given the state of SO search I'm not surprised duplicates have not been found.

**Problem 2**

A canonical on Python `sorted` is a bit like having a canonical each on SQL / Pandas / R merge. We get hundreds of questions every month asking how to *apply* merge methods, even while many canonicals exist beyond the official documentation.

An all-inclusive canonical would not help this problem, in my opinion. The questions will still come, and they will still be answered before 5 votes can be gathered. Answerers who spend the time to explain why a user's code is incorrect will feel their work is undervalued, you won't get them on board the VTC train either.

**An alternative suggestion**

The above demonstrates some problems with canonicals and why they aren't as effective as they should be. But what I'm a huge fan of is considering **specific problems or nuances** regarding usage of **common functions** and posting Q&As on these. A couple of examples below. [Apologies for the self-promotion: these are ones I can obviously find quickly.]

- [Nested lambda statements when sorting lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671990/nested-lambda-statements-when-sorting-lists)
- [Replace values in a pandas series via dictionary efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259580/replace-values-in-a-pandas-series-via-dictionary-efficiently)

These are short and snappy, like most SO Q&A, and seek to solve specific, yet common problems.

Answer (score -4):

The main problem with canonical questions is that the answers tend to be extremely low quality.

For example, if you look for answers about storing authentication data, you get this rubbish:

[Best way to authenticate user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708347/best-way-to-authenticate-user)

[How to authenticate user in Java code with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656767/how-to-authenticate-user-in-java-code-with-database)

[How to authenticate user according to their role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983080/how-to-authenticate-user-according-to-their-role)

In case it wasn't obvious, storing in plain text is the worst possible advice.

Another great example are these idiotic answers to a very simple question:

[Pick a random element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array)

1st upvote: (Answer that technically works but completely pedestrian, not generalized, etc)

2nd upvote: (mostly the same as #1, but with an added glaring bug)

4th or #th most upvoted: (probably the right answer)

So what I'm saying is that if we want canonical answers, there needs to be a much more robust way of filtering out drek. Up/down votes is just amplifies the incompetence.

Comment: Then you either write a better answer, pick the least-bad (/upvoted/ accepted) existing answer and improve it, or pick some other question as canonical/ ask a new one. Just gotta triage and get on with it... answers aren't gonna improve themselves ;-)

Comment: Okay, but say you do that... You need 300 up-votes to get anywhere near the top. In the mean time SO is giving terrible advice to beginners who can't recognize how bad these answers are.

Comment: no, I said **OR pick some other question as canonical/ ask a new one**. If a question is overrun with highly-upvoted crap answers, then abandon it, start a new one, and try to make the new one canonical.

Comment: Then your new question gets closed as a dupe. The system is fundamentally broken, guaranteed to produce, promote and protect bad answers.